# sed replace a single line

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying use sed to replace a single line.

Example:

```
space_left_action = EMAIL
admin_space_left_action = SUSPEND
```

I tried this command:

```
sed -i '/space_left_action*/c\space_left_action = SYSLOG' /etc/audit/auditd.conf
```

The result:

```
space_left_action = SYSLOG
space_left_action = SYSLOG
```

I do not want to replace the admin_space_left_action line, but still have the flexibility that if someone changes space_left_action value with something different sed will still replace the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use '^' for checking begining of line

```
sed -i '/^space_left_action*/c\space_left_action = SYSLOG' /etc/audit/auditd.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

you also can try this

```
sed -i '/[^_]space_left_action*/c\space_left_action = SYSLOG' /etc/audit/auditd.conf
```

Comment: Tried this..didn't work. EveryEvery's answer worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: For anyone who wants to know, what `[^_]` does is look for a character that is not `_`. So that fails because while it excludes "admin_space_left_action," it also excludes "space_left_action."

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version

```
awk '/^space_left_action/ {$3="SYSLOG"}1' /etc/audit/auditd.conf
space_left_action = SYSLOG
admin_space_left_action = SUSPEND
```